# there is a big gap on the left on where the cards is supposed to display

Tags: html, css

there is a  bbig gap on the left for some reason which make it overflow to the right even if i set it do even

I've tried putting it in chat gpt many time therefore showing weird comments, but the issue persists. How can I change my code to achieve the desired layout and behavior?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.container-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 36px;
  background-color: azure;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.container-icon button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
}

.heading {
  margin: 0px 0px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: azure;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 36px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.heading button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Set the card width to 200px */
.cards {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: azure;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 10px;
}

.main-cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /* Prevent wrapping to the next line */
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: azure;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <div class="heading">
        <header>
            <button class="icon-menu"><img width="20" height="20" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/menu--v3.png" alt="menu--v3"/></button>
            <input type="text" placeholder="search">
        </header>
    </div>
    
    <aside>
        <div class="container-icon">
            <button class="home-icons"><img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/home.png" alt="home"/></button>
            <button class="search-icons"><img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/search.png" alt="search"/></button>
            <button class="cart-icons"><img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/shopping-cart.png" alt="cart"/></button>
            <button class="user-icons"><img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/user.png" alt="user"/></button>
            <button class="menu-icons"><img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/menu.png" alt="menu"/></button>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <main>
        <div class="main-cards">
            <div class="cards card-1"></div>
            <div class="cards card-2"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry about the gibberish text on the bottm i didnt notice at first  and now i dont know how to undo thanks

Comment: Try adding `body {flex-direction: column}`. At the moment, the flex direction is row, meaning the elements are forced to sit side by side. (I wouldn't recommend using `display: flex` on the body element, but anyhow, that's your immediate issue.)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `body` has `display: flex` which by default positions its children horizontally.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want it looks like, Actually for such pages I prefer using **Bootstrap**, Anyway I wish this will help you.

**PS:** Check out the .heading class in CSS File , and I added an inner style line into your  in HTML file, comments are added.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.container-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 36px;
  background-color: azure;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.container-icon button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
}

.heading {
  margin: 0px 0px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 36px;
  
  /*Changed the **width** here*/

  width: 515px;
  background-color: azure;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 36px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.heading button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Set the card width to 200px */
.cards {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: azure;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 10px;
}

.main-cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /* Prevent wrapping to the next line */
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: azure;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <div class="heading">
        <header>
            <button class="icon-menu"><img width="20" height="20" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/menu--v3.png" alt="menu--v3"/></button>
            <input type="text" placeholder="search">
        </header>
    </div>
    
    <aside>
        <div class="container-icon">
            <button class="home-icons"><img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/home.png" alt="home"/></button>
            <button class="search-icons"><img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/search.png" alt="search"/></button>
            <button class="cart-icons"><img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/shopping-cart.png" alt="cart"/></button>
            <button class="user-icons"><img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/user.png" alt="user"/></button>
            <button class="menu-icons"><img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/menu.png" alt="menu"/></button>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- I added an inner style in **main** -->

    <main style="position: absolute;left: 37px;">
        <div class="main-cards">
            <div class="cards card-1"></div>
            <div class="cards card-2"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, just wondering what did you change to make it work

Comment: Check out the .heading class in CSS File , and I added an inner style line into your <main> in  HTML file

Comment: @The.Khalid You should update your answer and show specifically the part you added/changed to help other find your answer useful

Comment: @Lynxi Answer is updated now :)